# python programming to send an email - ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, connection

I'm new to programming .recently I was trying to learn how to send an email using Python on Windows 10.but there were some problems and I don't know what does this error mean.
Could someone help me?
here is my code :

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
msg=MIMEText("<h1>a heading</h1><p>hellothere!</p>","html")
msg['subject']='a test html message'
msg['from']='<mohammedbehjooarchich@gmail.com>'
msg['to']='<mohammedbehjooarchich@gmail.com>'
s=smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1')
s.sendmail('<mohammedbehjooarchich@gmail.com',['<mohammedbehjooarchich@gmail.com'],msg.as_string())
print('message sent')
```

Comment: Can you share the error that you received?

Comment: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.